# Search for java expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I often find myself searching for statements of a particular form in Java. Say I've written a simple function to express an idiom, such as "take this value, or a default value if it's null"

```
/** return a if not null, the default otherwise. */
public static <T> T notNull(T a, T def) {
    if (a == null)
        return def;
    else
        return a;
}
```

Now if I've written this, I want to look for cases in my code where it can be used to simplify, for instance

```
(some.longExpressionWhichMayBeNull() ? "default string" : some.longExpressionWhichMayBeNull())
```

The problem is that it's pretty tricky to write a regular expression that matches java syntax. It can be done, of course, but it's easy to get wrong.  It's hard to get regular expressions to ignore whitespace in all the right locations always accurately figure out where strings start and stop, know the difference between a cast and a function call etc.

It also seems a bit wasteful, since we already have a java parser, which does that already.

So my question is: is there some Java syntax aware alternative to regular expressions for searching for particular (sub-)expressions?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, and I'd either just clean up as I went along or do a file-by-file code review if I were in major refactor mode. This sort of idiom usually has a useful implementation in Apache Commons Lang; your specific example is taken care of by [ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#defaultIfNull(T,%20T)).

Comment: The default null thing was just an example, of a case where you change code so that there's a new way of doing something.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to match `( A ? B : A )` whilst correctly handling things like `( A ? ( B ? C : B ) : A )` ?

Comment: This question belongs Programmer SE site

Comment: IntelliJ has a feature called "structural search" which lets you search based on code patterns. It should help you find these instances.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to build an abstract syntax tree of the Java source file(s) and then analyse that. Might be possibly to leverage PMD (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) and write a custom rule (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/howtowritearule.html) to detect and flag expressions that could be optimised as you describe.